# Get matched result from two dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

The dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {142321: ['142321', 'vam@mail.com', 'IN', '4027'], 142322: ['142322', 'can@mail.com', 'IN', '4048'], 142323: ['142323', 'john@mail.com', 'GB', '4117'], 142324: ['142324', 'rohit@mail.com', 'CA', '15027']}

dict2 ={'142321': 'vam-k', '142322' : 'can-s', '142324' : 'rohit-j']
```

Match dict1 and dict2 and return below result:

```
new_dect = {142321: ['vam-k', 'IN', '4027'], 142322: ['can-s', 'IN', '4048'], 142324: ['rohit-j', 'CA', '15027']}
```

Comment: you seem to have forgotten to show the code you have tried that doesnt work and tell us what isnt working......

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary comprehension:

```
new_dect = {int(k): [v]+dict1[int(k)][-2:] for k,v in dict2.items()}

>>> new_dect
{142321: ['vam-k', 'IN', '4027'],
 142322: ['can-s', 'IN', '4048'],
 142324: ['rohit-j', 'CA', '15027']}
```